# Returning multiple CSV files zipped in HTTP GET response

Tags: spring-boot, csv, zip, java-11, apache-commons

I am using the following code (pseudocode/ MRE) to return a CSV file from the spring boot controller:

```
class ControllerClass {

  @GetMapping(produces = "text/csv")
  public void generateFiles(@RequestParam version) {
    File file = serviceClass.generateFiles(version);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
      .header(...)
      .contentLength(file.length())
      .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"))
      .body(new FileSystemResource(file))
  }
}

class ServiceClass {

  generateFiles(String version) {
    List < data > dataList = populate(verison);
    generateCsvFile(dataList, "file-name", headers);
  }

  generateCsvFile(...) {
    File file = new File("filename");
    CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat...build();
    ...
    // generate csv file using Apache commons csv CSVPrinter
    return file;
  }
}
```

The GET HTP method successfully returns the CSV file. But it also saves the CSV file in the project folder, which is not intended. An alternative would be to delete the files generated. But is there a way to send files without saving them to the server system?
Also, I have to return multiple CSV files as a response. So I am thinking of making a zip of them and returning it.
What libraries I could use to Zip the files and return them as a response?
**Some things I tried:**
https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress
The code here with the heading: `3. Zip Multiple Files` seems to be working fine.  Not sure if there is more succinct way to do it